# How to make a window transparent in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, compiz

I'm working with many GIS applications under Gnome. It sometimes is very convenient to place one map over another to quickly spot differences.

There used to be a KDE trick to make any window (not just a terminal!) transparent, thereby allowing me to make one map semi-transparent and place it on the window of the other mapping software. Is there a similar trick for Gnome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure about Gnomw itself, but in Compiz, there is a plugin called "Opacity, Brightness and Saturation adjustments", which allows you control transparency of windows any way I can imagine, including <kbd>Alt</kbd> + {sroll} as Andrea Lazzarotto said.

Comment: Also, make sure you enable **Animations**, found under Effects.

Comment: Note that this solution is not desirable with Gnome 3. `compiz` worked a lot better with the Unity desktop.

Answer (score 9):

Gnome extensions are OK, but if someone want use opacity/transparency occasionally - it is better use `xprop` command.

Run:

```
xprop -format _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 0x7FFFFFFF
```

and then click on window to set it to 50% opacity.

- `0x7FFFFFFF` - 50% opacity
- `0xFFFFFFFF` - 100% opacity

Set opacity via providing window id (obtained from `xwininfo`):

```
xprop -id 0x3a00006 -format _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 0x7FFFFFFF
```

Comment: this is best, as it works everywhere! (compiz transparency feature is missing for me)

Comment: `xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY \
  $(printf 0x%x $((0xffffffff * 30 / 100)))` Conveniece extension using printf for percentage to hexadecimal conversion. I have also made a short script as a desktop shortcut [documented here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1320458/258256)

Answer (score 6):

For newer versions of Gnome (Gnome 3/Gnome Shell), you can use [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/684/transparent-windows/) extension to make windows transparent:
[image]

#### EDIT: To install in Gnome 3.14+

Gnome extensions have a file containing which version of Gnome they are compatible with - this is not always correct as the extension may work for other versions not specified in the file, so you need to get the extension from outside the gnome extension site, and modify the file and install it manually - this works a lot of the time with other extensions.

1. Go the [the extension page](https://github.com/saysilence/transparentwindows), and download the [extension zip file](https://github.com/saysilence/transparentwindows/archive/master.zip).
2. Extract it, and modify the `shell-version` line in the `/transparentwindows-master/transparentwindows@ellen/metadata.json` file to make sure it includes your shell version (e.g. `3.14`):

   ```
    "shell-version": ["3.10", "3.12", "3.14"],
   ```

   <sup>You can find your shell version if needed using `gnome-shell --version`</sup>
3. Move the extracted files to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, so it looks like this:
   [image: /home/wilf/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/transparentwindows@ellen]
4. The extension should now work, though you may need to restart the shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+`r`+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and enable it in Gnome Tweak Tool or similar.

Also note that you can do a issue/bug report to the developer to ask for the extension the Gnome Extension site to be updated - in this case there is [one here](https://github.com/saysilence/transparentwindows/issues/9). You can also make your own commit to the extension to include 3.14+ versions.

Comment: this extension, does not work with GNOME 3.14 and LATER versions ... do you know extension compatible with current version ?

Comment: @Jiff - it does (i have used recently in 3.14), you just can't install it from the extension page. I''ll add how to install it in my answer

Comment: This extension is abandonware but it DOES work if you follow the instructions above

Comment: @JonathanLeaders out of interest, which shell version?

Comment: I have tested on `3.26.2`

Comment: The guy fucking deleted the entire repo. All hope is lost! Back to KDE ??

Comment: There is a old version (3.8... probably what I wrote this answer for!) at https://github.com/Stefanotis360/transparentwindows. It must be fairly recent as a version which supported  `["3.10", "3.12", "3.14", "3.22", "3.22.2"]` can be found in Google's cache. Versions up to `3.10` are on gnome extensions, updating used to be simple as uploading a zip but not sure now. I am wondeering it is a possiblity the code was not under a review spec for the site so the github user nuked the repo since this has been linked on the page for a month!

Answer (score 3):

Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and then scroll with your mouse wheel.

Comment: I believe this is Unity only and doesn't work in Gnome