# Is there an equivalent of Gnome Tweak Tool for XFCE?

Tags: xubuntu, 16.04, themes, xfce, gnome-tweak-tool

I've tried Gnome Tweak Tool on Xubuntu 16.04, but it didn't work for the themes or icons. Is there an equivalent that will work on Xubuntu 16.04?

Comment: There is a XFCE Theme Manager. http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/xfce-theme-manager-single-gui-to-change.html But it's an old project and it has already been integrated into XFCE 4.12 or newer. (aprox. Xubuntu 14.10 or newer).

Comment: *Gnome* tweak tool (like in *Gnome* Desktop Environment) will obviously not going to work for the *Xfce* Desktop Environment. They're completely unrelated aside the fact that they're both based on the GTK+ toolkit.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Well, it actually worked for some functions. But clearly, it's a bad idea to use it on XFCE.

Comment: Yes, that's because they share the theming related to only GTK+. This will work for any GTK+ application no matter your desktop environment or compositor (even those that aren't based on GTK+ like KDE).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply do not need one, XFCE is very customizable by default, you can do anything the tweak tools can do, right from the system settings.

You can change theme and icons through *Settings* → *Appearance* and window borders through *Settings* → *Window Manager*.

[This link](https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes) will give good detail on changing the various theme components.

Comment: But changing mouse cursors is not straight. The cursor works only Chrome window.

Comment: xfce is about as customisable as a rubics cube. fine, if you've got the leisure and want to work out the combination. a big pain the ears otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In my case to enable transparency changing compositor. F2 and type:

```
xfwm4-tweaks-settings 

tab compositing > Enable display compositing
```

There are a bunch of other interesting options in this tool. After figuring out the way I describe above I found another answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/100376).