# Transparent window in xfce (or compiz or at all)

Tags: xubuntu, compiz, xfce, xfwm4

So I tried using compiz for this and after hours of googling trying to figure out how to even turn it on, and what plugins to install, and whatever, I finally made the "scroll + button = transparency" work. But I couldn't grab, move, rezize windows anymore while compiz was turned on, and someone mentioned I could just do it within xfce window manager (xfwm), so I tried that instead..

in a post from 10 years ago someone says (alt + mousewheel) [How do I get transparent windows to show all windows beneath them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99333/how-do-i-get-transparent-windows-to-show-all-windows-beneath-them) but that just zooms in and out in 2021, (or I'm just doing something wrong). I can edit opacity of moving windows, or inactive ones, and other fancy stuff, all I'm asking for is setting the transparency of one specific window.

xfce 1.16, xUbuntu 21.04 (I think, idk where I can find out my current xUbuntu version tbh)

If there is an easier way to do this outside of xfce or compiz, but within xUbuntu, lmk