# Is it possible to set transparency per window in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, transparency

I like for example the function you've got per window "above other windows"
Is it also somehow possible to set transparency of a window?

Comment: It depends on which desktop environment you are using. Some DEs have more fine tuned controls than others. For example, window-specific rules have an entire section in the system settings for KDE, and that's in addition to the settings that affect transparency system wide. In GNOME you can't adjust any of these things using the system settings module.

Answer (score 7):

### From the Command Line

Ubuntu 20.04 should ship with a command line tool called `transset` which provides some useful options for setting the transparency of a window.

In my opinion, the options that work best for quickly changing a window's transparency level are the `-p` flag (which targets the window under the cursor) and the `--inc`/`--dec` flags (which respectively increase and decrease the transparency value by a given amount).

*Note that the transparency value is a decimal value between 0 and 1.*

To make the window more transparent:

```
$ transset -p --dec 0.05
```

To make the window more opaque:

```
$ transset -p --inc 0.05
```

---

### Making it better...

You can make it easier to toggle by pairing the aforementioned `transset` commands with `xbindkeys`. The following steps will make `Alt + MouseWheel UP` and `Alt + MouseWheel DOWN` control the opacity of the window under the cursor.

First, use `apt` (or `apt-get`) to install the tool:

```
$ sudo apt install xbindkeys
```

Then create and edit the `xbindkeys` configuration:

```
$ xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc && vi ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

Add the following lines to `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
...

"transset -p --inc 0.05"
  alt + b:4

"transset -p --dec 0.05"
  alt + b:5

...
```

Save and exit the configuration file and reload the xbindkeys configuration with:

```
$ killall xbindkeys
$ xbindkeys
```

Now you can use `Alt + MouseWheel UP/DOWN` to change the transparency of the window under the cursor.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I was having trouble using `picom` and `compton-trans` in conjunction. I use i3wm so putting `bindsym $mod+s exec --no-startup-id "transset --actual --dec 0.1"` worked great.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a non-standardized [Extended Window Manager hint](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/) named `_NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY` which can be modified with the [xprop](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xprop) tool.

```
xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY \
  $(printf 0x%x $((0xffffffff * 60 / 100)))
```

- where **60**, in this case, is the number you want to modify to  the desired transparency
- after executing the command your mouse pointer will turn into crosshairs and you need to click on the specific window you want to change its transparency on.

### Making it a desktop shortcut

- made a script with following content and saved it in `~/bin/xprop_transparency.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Set transparency percentage ? [Enter for 100%]" mydectrans
# only accept 10 to 99, rest is considered 100
[[ "$mydectrans" != [1-9][0-9] ]] && mydectrans=100
# Convert decimal to 32bit hex representation
my32bhextrans=$(printf 0x%x $((0xffffffff * $((mydectrans)) / 100)))
# Execute the action
xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY $my32bhextrans
```

- made a desktop shortcut with following content and save it in `~/.local/share/xpropTransparency.desktop`

  - Note: you have to expand `~` to full path , `/home/paui` in my case

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Set Window Transparency / Opacity
Exec=/home/paui/bin/xprop_transparency.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

- made both files executable `chmod u+x ~/bin/xprop_transparency.sh` , `chmod u+x ~/.local/share/xpropTransparency.desktop`

### how to check if your WM supports this hint:

Its not clear weather this method should be used to verify if your window manager supports it but you could try the following in a terminal window:

`xprop -root _NET_SUPPORTED | grep -o _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY`

if it appears in the results, then you can be pretty sure that your window manager supports this. If it doesn't appear, perhaps it works, perhaps not, you'll just have to try and see...

### Resources:

- [Article on setting this parameter](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/11/12/make-app-window-transparent-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/)
- [S/O answer setting opacity property within xlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39907274/2078851)
- [i3 Window manager enhancement issue discussion on the property](https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/2840)
- [Another question/answer on same topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/1109425/258256)
- [Yet Another question/answer on same topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494289/43437)

**Other software perhaps worth exploring**

- [Glassy GNOME](https://github.com/emiapwil/glassy-gnome)
- [pqiv image viewer](https://github.com/phillipberndt/pqiv) with [specific branch patch](https://github.com/phillipberndt/pqiv/pull/131) for transparent image with click through as described in [this post](https://mortoray.com/2018/08/04/creating-a-local-screen-overlay-for-streaming-obs-linux/)